# restrict showing root view controller from the detail view controller

Tags: ios, iphone

I am following this apple example.
 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html

I am creating an application in which user can perform different activities after the login. I wants to disable/restrict the root view controller(menu from left side appears with the right swipe) when the login screen appears in the detail view controller. After the user login, the left menu should appears when we swipe (which is currently implemented in this example).

Kindly help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier to create a login view controller and present it when the application starts and on when login succeeds, present the current split view controller.

In the example, the current view controller is set with: self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;

Comment: Yes Andrei. This is the other way of doing it. But consider a situation in which the user select the setting option from root view controller(left menu). Here you want to restrict the user to enter password to go to the settings and you dont allow the user to go back after this transition for security check. If we do not want to push the view controller again and again on screen then what will be its work around??